# Collecting code coverage with dotnet test on azure devops yaml pipeline

Tags: unit-testing, .net-core, code-coverage, azure-pipelines

I've tried all I can find to figure this out.

I have several fresh .net core 3.1 or .net standard 2 projects that are building on Azure DevOps Services. I'm trying to setup the code coverage for these projects and I'm getting nowhere.

When running a test locally I get a success and the code coverage result is created.

```
3/24/20 3:39 [jgust] [portChangesFromAggregateRepo ≡]
>: dotnet test .\Common.UnitTests\ --collect:"Code coverage"
Test run for C:\src\bio\lib\Common\src\Common.UnitTests\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\Common.UnitTests.dll(.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.2)
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 16.3.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Starting test execution, please wait...

A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.

Attachments:
  C:\src\bio\lib\Common\src\Common.UnitTests\TestResults\74f826e4-4a46-46dd-9fe5-7fd17b8cee1c\2020-03-24.15_40_28.coverage
Test Run Successful.
Total tests: 794
     Passed: 794
 Total time: 19.3390 Seconds
```

However, when running this project on Azure DevOps, the build reports that the collector can't be found.

```
A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
Data collection : Could not find data collector 'Code coverage'
Results File: d:\a\_temp\VssAdministrator_fv-az130_2020-03-24_20_53_07.trx

Test Run Successful.
Total tests: 794
     Passed: 794
```

The pipeline task for this is as follows:

[image]

and yes I'm using windows platform here

[image]

What am I missing about setting up code coverage collection for these projects.

As far as I can tell, I'm going everything [strait out of the book](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/dotnet-core?view=azure-devops#collect-code-coverage)

Also, I am using the described version of package:

`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.9.0" />`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should specify the path to the csproj file(s) of your test project in `Path to project(s)`, and make sure the test project reference [Microsoft.NET.Test.SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NET.Test.SDK) version 15.8.0 or higher

While specifying paths to the `.dll` files will enable the `dotnet test` command under the task to run the tests, it will not allow the collection of coverage data. That operation requires paths to `.csproj` files.

Try using 
`$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\**\*${{ parameters.slnName }}*[T|t]est*.csproj`

Note: this specification should make the negations obsolete.

Comment: My task specifies a number of new line separated mini-match patterns for the projects input, which is described as appropriate. I don't necessarily have only one unit test project and want to run any test .dll the pipeline can find in the repo with exclusions for long running or integration tests. Also, I am referencing the appropriate version of the Test.SDK. I've edited my question to denote this.

Comment: Do I need to change the value of that input to be any matching `.csproj` file instead of any matching `.dll`?

Comment: I have added the args to do the code coverage collection into our pipeline. It runs without any pipeline errors but after all done, it still says, "setup code coverage". What am i missing here?

Comment: i got it figured. I had to install the nuget for Coverlet and then configure the rest in the pipeline to publish.