# How can code coverage be obtained in an Azure YAML pipeline using the VSTest@3 task?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, code-coverage, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am currently setting up a YAML pipeline that includes test execution. Here are my test tasks:

```
- task: VisualStudioTestPlatformInstaller@1
  inputs:
    packageFeedSelector: 'nugetOrg'
    versionSelector: 'latestStable'

- task: VSTest@3
  inputs:
    testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
    testAssemblyVer2: |
      **\References\Client.Debug\**\*test.dll
  searchFolder: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)'
  runInParallel: false
  codeCoverageEnabled: true
  platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
  configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
  diagnosticsEnabled: true
  pathtoCustomTestAdapters: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)\References\Client.Debug\'
```

I've specified a custom folder where the test DLLs can be found because the solution has a specific logic. After building the solution, many DLLs, including the *.test.dll files, are copied into this folder. I also need to specify a path to the test adapter since the adapter's DLL is also copied to this directory.

The test task works fine, and all tests are executed with statistics shown in Azure DevOps. However, the code coverage is not displayed, and the output of the VSTest@3 task indicates that data collection cannot be performed:

```
...
Starting test execution, please wait...
A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
Blame: Attaching crash dump utility to process testhost.net48 (6444).
Data collection : Unable to find a datacollector with a friendly name 'Code Coverage'.
Data collection : Could not find the data collector 'Code Coverage'
NUnit Adapter 4.5.0.0: Test execution started
...
```

What should I do to make code coverage work and display the statistics in Azure DevOps? It doesn't have to be the Coverlet package; it can also be the one from Microsoft. The main thing is that code coverage works.

I also came across this question: [dotnet test is unable to find a datacollector with friendly name 'Code Coverage'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69962187/dotnet-test-is-unable-to-find-a-datacollector-with-friendly-name-code-coverage). It is mentioned that one can use .csproj files instead of `.dll`'s, and then code coverage should work. However, I am using the VSTest@3 task, and for this task, I can only specify assemblies, test plans, and test runs under the "Select tests using" field. The option to specify ".csproj files" is not provided.

There is also this question: [Collecting code coverage with dotnet test on azure devops yaml pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60839895/collecting-code-coverage-with-dotnet-test-on-azure-devops-yaml-pipeline). The `DotNetCoreCli` task is utilized, and the suggestion is again to use `.csproj` files instead of .dlls. However, I still don't see any option to specify the `.csproj` files for the task I am using.

Update: This is the `.csproj` file of one of my test projects:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>disable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>disable</Nullable>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="4.0.1" />
      <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="4.5.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="coverlet.msbuild" Version="6.0.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Include="..\path\to\project.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```